# Strange evaluation of boolean expression

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, operator-precedence

why is the value of the following expression false?

```
bool a = false;
bool b= true;
std::cout<< a || !b && !a || b;
```

and why does the value changes when adding parenthesis

```
bool a = false;
bool b= true;

std::cout<< (a || !b && !a || b);
```

Shouldn't the parenthesis be putted like this:

```
a || (!b && !a) || b
```

, and the result be `false` or `false` or `true` equal `true`?

Comment: Read about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in [any good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558). And remember that `<<` is really the *left bitwise shift* operator.

Comment: See the [compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32322c6b4b38148e) you'll get with that code.

Comment: && has an higher precedence than ||, so the value should be true.

Comment: Seems like you either didn't read or didn't understand the comments. `<<` has even higher precendence, so the first code is interpreted as `(std::cout<< a) || !b && !a || b`.

Comment: ok now I've got it thank you

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, in the first case, the expression is due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) evaluated as

```
(std::cout << a) || !b && !a || b;
```

Result of `std::cout << a` is a reference to the `std::cout` object itself, which is in C++03 convertible to `bool` through `operator void*()` inherited from `std::basic_ios`. In C++11, there is `operator bool()` instead, which allows so-called *contextual conversion*.

The rest is therefore just a boolean expression and its result is discarded.